# Moving from MySQL->PostGres: Best Way to Store PHP Objects in MySQL, Retrieve in PostGres?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have a a MySQL database that stores PHP objects in serialized format to a BLOB field. I'm moving this database from MySQL -> PostGres.

So far I have found no way to move those PHP objects to PostGres. Saving the objects serialized to a MySQL field of type BLOB or MySQL LongText, and importing into PostGres Text or ByteA, apparently fails to bring the data over when imported.

I'm happy to write special-purpose code to store the PHP objects in any way that will work. What's a good way to store them in MySQL so as to import them into PostGres?

**Note:** Per request of StackOverflow, this question is different from [Storing large JSON - binary or text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198808), because that question does not reference postgres.

Comment: This person seems to have found an answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/how-to-migrate-large-blob-table-from-mysql-to-postgresql about migrating a blob table to PostgreSQL.

Comment: store as JSONB instead, or just json in the text/blob field, and then import into a JSON field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing large JSON - binary or text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198808/storing-large-json-binary-or-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data transfer tool (Valentina Pro), copied the mySQL BLOB fields to PostGres ByteA fields. This code retrieved the serialized string from the contents of this field:

`$serializedString = pg_unescape_bytea($contentsOfPostGresByteAField);`

Thanks to [Sergey Pashkov](http://valentina-db.com/en/discussion-forums/2727-moving-from-mysql-postgres-best-way-to-store-php-objects-in-mysql,-retrieve-in-postgres#reply-2741) for the tip!