# update a dict value in mysql with new key and value pairs

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am looking for a way to update a DB column(attributes) which is of mediumtext type and contains some value like below.

```
{"id_real": "50", "id_virt": "40"}
```

Table structure is as below:

```
mysql> desc cust_cache;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | varchar(250) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type       | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| attributes | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I need to update this dict with some other extra key and value.

so new value will be as follows:

```
{"id_real": "50", "id_virt": "40", "purchase_status":"done", "payment":"done"}
```

I am trying to figure out the way for updating the field at single update query without reading a value and appending then updating it.

Expecting a way to do in python.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing large JSON - binary or text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198808/storing-large-json-binary-or-text)

Comment: why it is tagged with python

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Updated the question, Expecting a python code, I need to do in python

Comment: You need to use a mysql client https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python to do this.

Comment: @e4c5 I am expecting in python not in PHP .

Comment: The programming language isn't the issue here. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: please add more information on how the needed data (purchase_status, payment) is stored